# Triggering of Excel Function

Tags: vba, excel

```
Worksheets("InputSheet").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
```

After excution of this Line, A UDF is triggered and and this UDF ends abruptly for reasons unknown to me.

The UDF is not called directly anywhere in "InputSheet" . Only a NamedCell which is in another sheet using this function is used in "InputSheet".

I dont want the function to be triggered.
Any possible reasons or solutions

Comment: Seeing your file would help us a lot. Seeing your UDF may help somewhat.

Comment: This might have been triggered from the PERSONAL.XLSB workbook. Check all events in there and remove the call to this function

Comment: I never played around with Personal.XLSB

Answer (score 1):

Showing and hiding rows often triggers a recalculation, and recalculations involve all worksheets in all open workbooks.
Try setting calculation to Manual.

Comment: Woudnt setting the calculation to Manual make the function not to recalculate when its parameters change.?

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but you can set calculation to manual directly before this line and set it back to automatic directly afterwards and you should get around the issue.